# Distribution of the average

Tags: statistics, central-limit-theorem

If the true population average is 15 and we are going to take a random sample and calculate the average 1,000,000 times, what is the distribution of the estimated average?

My thoughts:

By the CLT, $\frac{\bar{x} - E\bar{x}}{\sqrt{Var {\bar{x}}}} \sim Normal(0,1)$ as the number of trials to calculate the mean approaches infinity.
So, the distribution of the estimated average should be $Normal(15, Var(\bar{x}))$, but $Var(\bar{x})= Var(X)/n$, where $X$ is a random number from the population and $n$ is the size of the random sample.

Is this right?
So, are the random samples should be of the same size n?

Answer (score 1):

The Central Limit Theorem states that the distribution of the *sample mean* approaches a normal distribution *as the sample size approaches infinity*.

If you have a fixed sample size, then the sampling distribution will not actually be normal in most cases - for a very simple example, if the sample size is 1 then the distribution of the sample mean is the distribution of the population (because all you're doing is measuring one value from the population at a time).

However, if the sample mean is "big enough", then you can indeed say that the distribution of the sample mean is *approximately* normal, with the distribution you say, assuming that the sample is of fixed size. As it stands, the question seems to be missing some key information to comment more accurately.

Comment: I am not sure. They are saying that you get a sample a million times. So, I think they take a sample, get the mean, then repeat the process. This is how they get  a sample of means. Am I right regarding the understanding of the question? The question is "what probability distribution would the estimated averages approximate?"

Comment: I had the same question about the exact process described in the question, but I see nothing wrong with what is said in this answer. (+1)

Comment: &BruceET So, as a previous commenter said, if the size of each sample is 1, but we do sampling 1 million times and thus get 1 million averages, they will still follow normal distribution, right?

Comment: &ConMan  When you said "the sample mean is "big enough", did you mean the sample size "big enough"?

Comment: I did mean sample size, my mistake. And if you draw a million samples, each of size 1, then you're just drawing a million values from the population - which follows the distribution of the population itself. So if the population has, say, a uniform distribution, then you'd expect the million samples to be uniform too.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:** I'm wondering (a) if the following shows what you're doing, and (b) What is the purpose of this? A classroom demonstration on the CLT?
Or something else?

In R, we simulate a million realizations of $A = \bar X,$
the sample average of $n = 900$ values from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 15, \sigma = 3).$

```
set.seed(506)
a = replicate( 10^6, mean(rnorm(900, 15, 3)) ) 
 mean(a)
[1] 14.99992     # aprx E(samp avg) = 15
var(a)
[1] 0.009992273  # aprx V(samp avg) = 9/900 = 0.01
```

Histogram of the one million sample averages $A = \bar X.$
The red curve is the density of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 15, \sigma = 1/10).$

```
hist(a, prob=T, br=40, col="skyblue2")
  curve(dnorm(x, 15, 1/10), add=T, col="red")
```

[image]

Again, but with data sampled from a (right-skewed) exponential distribution. [R uses rate parameter $\lambda = 1/\mu]:$

```
set.seed(2010)
a = replicate( 10^6, mean(rexp(900, .1)) ) 
mean(a)
[1] 10.00039     # aprx E(samp mean) = 10
var(a)
[1] 0.1112148    # aprx Var(samp mean) = 100/900 = 0.1111
```

This time the distribution of $A = \bar X$ is very nearly normal,
but not *exactly*
(still a tiny bit of skewness, hardly visible in plot).
 The red curve is the density of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 10, \sigma = 1/3);$ the (almost coincident) black dotted curve is the density
curve of the exact distribution $\mathsf{Gamma}(\mathrm{shape}=900, \mathrm{rate} = 90)$ of $A = \bar X.$

```
hist(a, prob=T, br=40, col="skyblue2")
  curve(dnorm(x, 10, 1/3), add=T, col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: It is a question asked in the homework for an intro stats class. What you are showing is exactly how I understood the question . If it was getting a sample of size of 1 million every time, finding its mean and repeat the process to get a sample of means, then I would accept that it's normally distributed. But the actual question doesn't specify the sample size. It just says that we are getting 1 million samples.

Comment: Good:  If data are normal, then $n$ doesn't matter because the sample mean will be normal also, regardless of $n.$ Then the issue is to show that $Var(\bar X) = \sigma^2/n.$  If data are not normal, then $n$ should be large enough that the dist'n of $\bar X$ is nearly normal. (For exponential data, $n=900$ seems large enough.